# VBA: Change font color on every nth cell based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have managed to get code working that will grey out an entire row based on the value of a cell.

Now I need: 
If cell value in AV < 100, change the font color in every 6th column, starting column 6. 
Then if value in AW < 100, change the font color in every 6th column, starting column 7.
Then if value in AX < 100, change the font color in every 6th column, starting column 8.
I need to do this with every value in Range AV:AZ.

I'd really appreciate some help.

This is the code I managed to get working to grey out an entire row:

```
    Range("AU1").Select
    For i = 12 To LRow                                                'Do for Row 12 to end
        If Cells(i, 47).value < 100 Then
            Cells(i, 47).EntireRow.Font.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: alternatively you can consider conditional formatting, it will work more efficiently.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't. This is one very small sub-segment of a large file that has to be automated. I have to be able to use VBA to achieve this. The reporting template gets rolled out over 20 identical individual reports. Conditional formatting across 20 reports, will unfortunately simply not be efficient. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by removing the "`EntireRow`" and use of `Offset` instead

```
Range("AU1").Select
For i = 12 To LRow      'Do   for Row 12 to end
    If Cells(i, 47).value < 100 Then
        For j = 1 to 10  ' this must be tuned to your need.
          Cells(i, 47).Offset(0, 6*j +1).Font.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
        Next j
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you so much. However, that isn't working for me at all. And, furthermore, if I add your code in with my existing working code, that suddenly doesn't work either. The piece of code I posted above was working perfectly. What I need is in addition to the working code: If Col AV < 100, then from Col 6 and for every 6th column thereafter up to Col AV, change the font color in Col 6 and every 6th column.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I didn't read till the end. Then you need to do then is to have an inner loop. I can't tune it up from here since I don't have excel, but we'll see tomorrow. I'll edit with the basic idea - you can try tuning it for your need.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I'm going to plug in your suggestion and will revert. Much appreciated.